# Can I access LINQPad's C# code from html elements?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have C# code that encrypt/decrypt strings.

```
void Main()
{

    string myParameters = "val=tKsXHtj03UhASw4TRFMlqg%3d%3d";
    Calc(myParameters).Dump();

}

string Calc(string str)
{
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        //return from WEBAPI....
    }
}
```

But I also know that I can create html via `Util.RawHtml` , so I *won't need to change the code every time*.

So , I added this :

```
Util.RawHtml("<input type='text' id='tbData' /><br/><br/> <input type='button' id='btnCalc' value='Calc'/><br/> <br/> ").Dump();
```

So now it looks like :

[image]

But I need to run C# code from the button click ( which is html)

**Question:**

Is it possible to do such thing with Linqpad ?

How can I run `Calc()` after clicking the button? ( and read the value from the textbox)

linqpad: 4.55.03 (anycpu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but in the absence of a proper answer, here are two alternative methods which I have used which might help

The first is simply using Util.ReadLine() in a loop, eg

```
void Main()
{
    do
    {
        Calc(Util.ReadLine()).Dump();
    }
    while (true);
}

string Calc(string str)
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        return "from WEBAPI....";       
    }   
}
```

The second is to use WPF elements rather then HMTL, eg

```
void Main()
{
    var lbl1 = new TextBlock{ Text = "Input value ", MinWidth = 70 } ;
    var lbl2 = new TextBlock{ Text = "Results     ", MinWidth = 70  } ;

    var tb  = new TextBox{   MinWidth = 500 } ;

    var btn = new Button { Content = " Calc " };
    btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    btn.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5,1,1,1);
    btn.MaxWidth = 100;

    var results = new TextBlock{ Text = ""  } ;
    btn.Click += (sender, args) => { results.Text = Calc(tb.Text); } ;

    var panel1 = new DockPanel();
    panel1.Children.Add(lbl1);
    panel1.Children.Add(tb);
    panel1.Children.Add(btn);

    var panel2 = new DockPanel();
    panel2.Children.Add(lbl2);
    panel2.Children.Add(results);

    PanelManager.StackWpfElement(panel1, "Example");
    PanelManager.StackWpfElement(panel2, "Example");
}
```

which should produce something like

[image: Screenshot]